# how do i publish a organization project to github with intellij

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I've created a github repository and trying to push my project to it with through intellij. 
however it's always getting shared to the personal account not the repository that I've created.

My personal account is also located in the repository. Is there a way to tell intellij to share to the repository instead of the personal one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

1. Open GitHub, using "Transfer" under "Settings" for the repository you want to move..
   enter the repository name you want to add to your organization. And 
   "New owner's GitHub username" this will be the username of your organization.

That's it. This will move the project to your organization.

Refer: https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-a-repository/

2. And i do not think you need to make any changes while you checkout/checkin from your IDE. I'm using Intellij and after moving the project to organization.. i was able to make commits to the repository that i moved to the organization using my personal user-name/pwd (and not the organization).

Comment: This solution stop working for me. After transfer project on GitHub I lost ability to push with my current login and password.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't seem to work for me. IDEA appears to commit, but the commits don't actually show up in the repo

Comment: Has anyone managed to get this to work?  I really need to use this, but I can't get working

Answer (score 3):

Before pushing your project to Github, bring up the console and type:

`git remote add origin https://github.com/<your organization>/<your project>.git`